# Bug While i try to compare

Tags: c

Actually i have a little bug with this code:

```
printf("Estadio Nemesio Diez\n\n");
for(i=0;i<12;i++)
{
  if(ultimoAnoDiez[0]==ultimoAnoDiezOriginal[i]);
  {
    mes=i;
  }
}
```

i am comparing 2 arrays, and im selecting the index[0], because that array is already sorted, but when i compile and execute the file, the program says that all the values on each array is the same, but if i print the values of each array all are diferents.

I will appreciate the help

BTW Im programmin on C

Comment: If you are programming (and compiling) C, don't tag C++. The modern languages can be very different.

Comment: please include more code with the variables declared and defined so on

Comment: If I would have to guess, I'd say that either: in this example, ultimoAnoDiezOrigina[11] happens to be the same as ultimoAnoDiez[0], or: mes isn't initialised correctly.

Comment: Loop: If non_equal_condition, break and report non equal. Otherwise the loop finishes and it is equal.

Comment: @MrLister that would be the logical explanation

Comment: @deW1 But I don't want to have to guess. I want to see the complete code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there can be two reasons:

### First

your if condition is ending with `;` (making `{/* othet statement */}` a block but not if block)

### Second

```
(ultimoAnoDiez[0]==ultimoAnoDiezOriginal[i])
```

should be (you should be comparing individual values and not all values(i) to first value(0) only)

```
(ultimoAnoDiez[i]==ultimoAnoDiezOriginal[i]);
```

Further to check for array equality you return as soon as you find unequal values so it should be like

```
int mes = 12;
for(i=0;i<12;i++)
{
  if(ultimoAnoDiez[i]!=ultimoAnoDiezOriginal[i])
  {
    mes=i;
    break;
  }
}
if(mes < 12){
//UNEqual
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt most compilers give an error with a `;` at the end of an `if` statement?

Also, he is comparing individual values by incrementing `i`.

Comment: They will give a warning and not an error, I think. Yes edited the code

Comment: It's wrong now. The part after the if will always be executed now, not just if the condition is true.

Comment: @MrLister You are right, I was using left navigation and saving causing incorrect edits, extremely sorry for that. Corrected the code. ;(

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary But you still have the "`if (..)` should be `if (..);`" in the first half of your answer. That semicolon (which is what the OP has) should be in the first sentence, not the second!

Comment: It is  if(ultimoAnoDiez[i]`!=`ultimoAnoDiezOriginal[i]) and not  if(ultimoAnoDiez[i]`==`ultimoAnoDiezOriginal[i]) so it will break as soon as unequal value is found. I am trying to find inequality.

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary I'm trying to agree with you, but I'm saying the OP has the `;` in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on that. I thought differently, sorry for that

Comment: @DurgeshChaudhary that was the problem!! haha... i didnt notice that semicolon XD, and the compiler havent tell me something about my sintaxis Thanks a lot